# JMenuItem ActionListener Is Not Working Properly

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jmenuitem

i have made JAVA code using Jmenulist and try to call it by actionlistener, but ActionListner is not working.Altough it is working in another code.bt it is creating problem in the program.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Submit {



public static void main(String[] args) 
{

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Graph");


JMenuItem closeMenuItem = new JMenu("Close");
 closeMenuItem.addActionListener(new Close());


fileMenu.add(closeMenuItem);

menuBar.add(fileMenu);

frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setVisible(true);
}


}


 class Close implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    System.out.println("Selected: ");

}}
```

When i complie it

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    System.out.println("Selected: ");

}
```

This section is not working. While Almost same code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package in.ac.iiitd.cse201.rachit11084.hw3.q2;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Selected: " + e.getActionCommand());

  }
}

public class ContructMenuActionListener {
  public static void main(final String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MenuSample Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();


    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);


    JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
    newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.setSize(350, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Is working fine.
How should I solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the expected result and what is happening? describe the problem in more detail

Answer (score 3):

`JMenuItem closeMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Close");`

not

`JMenuItem closeMenuItem = new JMenu("Close");`

The `new JMenu` creates a new sub-menu, so it cannot have an action associated, it only offers sub-menu items.